# How can i convert C# header to delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

How can I write this in Delphi code?

```
[DllImport("FT_ND_API.dll")]
public static extern uint epas_CreateContext(out IntPtr hContextHandle, 
    uint ulFlags, uint ulApiVersion);

[DllImport("FT_ND_API.dll")]
public static extern uint epas_OpenDevice(IntPtr hContextHandle, 
    uint ulQueryType, IntPtr pQueryData);

[DllImport("FT_ND_API.dll")]
public static extern uint epas_GetProperty(IntPtr hContextHandle, uint ulFlags, 
    IntPtr pRefData, byte[] pPropData, uint ulPropSize);

[DllImport("FT_ND_API.dll")]
public static extern uint epas_CreateDir(IntPtr hContextHandle, uint ulFlags, 
    String pucName, String pucGuid, ref WDirInfo pDirInfo, uint ulSizeOfDirInfo);
```

Comment: Actually, your question is "How can I call method in a DLL from Delphi".

Comment: @axrwkr: I expect the OP to understand what I said, and why, in order to give the opportunity to think of a better title. I'm only suggesting a title, but it may improved by the op itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
function epas_CreateContext(
  out hContextHandle: NativeInt; 
  ulFlags: Cardinal; 
  ulApiVersion: Cardinal
): Cardinal; stdcall; external 'FT_ND_API.dll';

function epas_OpenDevice(
  hContextHandle: NativeInt; 
  ulQueryType: Cardinal; 
  pQueryData: IntPtr
): Cardinal; stdcall; external 'FT_ND_API.dll';

function epas_GetProperty(
  hContextHandle: NativeInt; 
  ulFlags: Cardinal; 
  pRefData: NativeInt; 
  pPropData: PByte; 
  ulPropSize: Cardinal
): Cardinal; stdcall; external 'FT_ND_API.dll';

function epas_CreateDir(
  hContextHandle: NativeInt; 
  ulFlags: Cardinal; 
  pucName: PAnsiChar; 
  pucGuid: PAnsiChar; 
  var pDirInfo: WDirInfo; 
  ulSizeOfDirInfo: Cardinal
): Cardinal; stdcall; external 'FT_ND_API.dll';
```

Notes:

- `IntPtr` is a pointer sized integer. In Delphi that is `NativeInt`.
- `uint` is an unsigned 32 bit integer, `Cardinal` in Delphi.
- `string` gets marshalled to a C string, pointer to null-terminated string. Since there is no `CharSet` specified, the default of `CharSet.Ansi` is used. That's `PAnsiChar` in Delphi.
- No `CallingConvention` is specified so the default of `CallingConvention.StdCall` applies. So, that's `stdcall` in Delphi.
- The `byte[]` is an array of bytes. That's marshalled as a pointer to the first byte of the array. So, `PByte` in Delphi.
- You will also need to translate `WDirInfo` to Delphi. It looks like it might be a struct.

You might be better off working from the C++ header file rather than the p/invoke declarations. It's always best to work from the original source of an interface definition.